# Union of map and interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to express a type that CAN have ANY properties, but MUST have certain properties.

So, creating the type would throw a compile time error if a property is not set, but using a property not pre-defined would also not throw an error.

```
interface MyInterface {
    id: string;
}

function createObject(): MyInterface {
    const myObject: MyInterface = {
        id: "abc123",
        someOtherProperty: "yadda yadda"
    };
    return myObject;
}

const myObject = createObject();

console.log(myObject.id);
console.log(myObject.someOtherProperty);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing my question, I realized the answer was an Intersection type. Thanks rubber duckies.

```
type MyIdAbleType = { id: string } & { [key: string]: any }
```